# Why is the Databind() for my Gridview so slow?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a Gridview which I populate from a MySQL database. Even though the `DataSource` only contains 20 rows, it needs about 5 seconds for the `Databind()` to execute.

```
private void fill_gvTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = Connection.Query("SELECT CompanyName, Street, Logo, Username FROM portalusers WHERE usertyp = 0");

        gvTable.DataSource = dt;
        gvTable.DataBind();
    }
```

All of the data is a string, except the logo which is a mediumblob. How can I speed up this process?

Comment: What is the size of the blob?  What kind of database are you connecting to? Where is the database located?  What type of network connection is between the data source and the client?

What is that "Connection" class doing?  Could there be something in there causing it? Is it a third party package? Or something you built yourself?

Comment: @DCCoder 1. Mediumblob 2. MySQL 5.7.18  3. on a server ~3km from my location 4. don't know what you excatly mean by that I grab the data with Odbc Connection. But I don't understand why this questions would be useful, the database is not the problem the query is executed in less than 2 ms.

Comment: I'm not that concerned about the database itself, but I feel as though your connection to the database could be the issue.  Not for certain, but that's usually the case with slow returns like this.   

Also, I've used Amazon Aurora in the past and if the database is resting it takes about as long for a query to complete which is why I was asking some of the other questions.

Comment: A medium blob can also go up to 16MBs, depending on your connection speed that could slow it down as well.  I would store the image on a server and just reference its location in the DB.

Comment: @DCCoder I also thought about that but I removed the image and it still needs about 4 seconds